# Azure Pipelines: file-trigger for files on root level

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

How do I add all files on root-level as trigger to an Azure Devops - Pipeline?

Currently my setup looks like this:

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'
  paths:
    include:
      - '*' # this matches all files in the repository
      - apps/*
```

with the intention that the pr-builds are triggered by changes to root-level files (i.e. `package.json`) and files within the apps-folder. However including `*` does match ALL files in my repository instead of the root-level files.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) can't help me out here. Is there a way to include all root-level files to the trigger without manually including every single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have pipeline triggered only for changes in your root folder you need to exclude all folder in `exclude` section:

```yaml
pr:
 branches:
   include:
     - master
 paths:
   include:
     - '*'
   exclude:
     - 'stackoverflow/*'
     - 'abc/*'
     - 'xyz/*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here agree with Krzysztof Madej,  `'*' # same as '/' for the repository root` , here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards) you can refer to . If you do not want the sub-files of the folders in the root directory to trigger the pipeline, you need to add `exclude` to the `paths` filter.

For example:

```
trigger:
      branches:
        include:
         - master
      paths:
        include:
         - '*'
        exclude:
          - '/test01/'
```

[image]

Then the changes to the `test0` file will not trigger the pipeline.